# Is $(3-i)(i)$ an irreducible factorization of $1+3i$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers

I know there is another similar question out there, but I cannot comment on it to ask a question pertaining to my solution.

The question: The Gaussian Integers, $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, are a UFD. Factor each of the following elements in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ into a product of irreducibles.

Recall: $p\in D$ is irreducible if when $p=ab$, then either a or b is a unit.

Factor $1+3i$.

I got $1+3i = (i)(3-i)$, but is this a factorization that is irreducible?

Comment: $i$ is a unit with inverse $-i.$

Comment: Also, $3-i$ isn't irreducible.  (Can you factor it?)

Comment: $1^2 + 3^2 = 10 = 2 \cdot 5$

Comment: Yeah, I know how to factor it using the norm. I wanted to know why my original one wasn't correct.

Comment: @mathnoob If you know how to factor it that way then it's obviously _not_ irreducible.